# Get URI of the shared preferences .xml file from the internal storage

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm creating an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` that sends different information regarding the current state of the device/application

I'm having trouble attaching the shared preferences file URI to that intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
intent.setType("application/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[] {"support@example.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email body - Debug info");
// THE IMPORTANT PART
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,fileUriList);
```

where `fileUriList` is an `ArrayList<Uri>` containing:

- the SQLite database file which I successfully got from the `ContentProvider`
- **the shared preferences file URI - which I am not able to get**

How the provider is registered in the manifest

```
<provider
    android:name="._android._providers.MyFileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

@xml/provider_paths:

```
<paths>
    <cache-path name="cache_internal_storage" path="." />
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

This is how I'm trying to get the URI to the shared preferences file:

```
String spFilePath = getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/shared_prefs/main_sp.xml";
File sharedPrefsMain = new File(spFilePath);
Uri spUri = MyFileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", sharedPrefsMain);
```

I'm getting the following error message:

> Failed to find configured root that contains
> /data/data/ro.example.example/shared_prefs/main_sp.xml

**How can I properly get the shared preferences .xml file from the internal private memory?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android 10- add this to your privider_paths.xml file:

```
 <root-path name="root" path="." />
```

Otherwise copy your file to getFilesDir() and share from there using:

```
 <files-path name="private" path="."/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`FileProvider` does not serve from arbitrary locations, and `shared_prefs` is outside of what it supports. You would need to create your own `ContentProvider` to serve that file.